# Issue with using SUM function in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using

```
select sum(value1-value2) as Result from tbl
```

it is working fine but when I try to use

```
select id,name,sum(value1-value2) as Result from tbl
```

it does not work.

What can be the solution?

Comment: Sum is an aggregate function.  Are you trying to add up all the values in a column, or are you just trying to get the result of value1 - value2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `group by` if you want the value for each id/name:

```
select id, name, sum(value1-value2) as Result
from tbl
group by id, name;
```

Otherwise, you need to put them in aggregate functions:

```
select min(id), min(name), sum(value1-value2) as Result
from tbl;
```

Or, if you just want the difference on each row, then omit the `sum()`:

```
select id, name, (value1-value2) as Result
from tbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

when you using sum(), you should add group by

```
select id,name,sum(value1-value2) as Result
from tbl
group by id, name
```

Comment: There is no need to add `Result` to the group by clause

Comment: thanks about you correction. This should be do not use group by Result